# Why can't I run git add -uA?

Tags: git

Before committing, I usually use the following command to add newly created files to the repository:

```
git add -A
```

Then, I run the following command to remove deleted files from the repository:

```
git add -u
```

When I try to run these commands together, I'm told they are mutually exclusive:

```
git add -uA
```

I'm obviously missing something. Why are these commands mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `git add -A` does everything that `git add -u` does, plus some extra:

```
   -A, --all
       Like -u, but match <filepattern> against files in the working tree in addition to
       the index. That means that it will
       find new files as well as staging modified content and removing files that are no
       longer in the working tree.
```

`git add -A` should be sufficient for what you are doing.